# Stop Combining Nested Values with XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

I am trying to parse an XML document with XmlSlurper. This document has a lot of nested elements, and each one has a value. It follows this format:

```
<XML version="1" title="cars" lot="23">
<Cars>
    <Car year="2012" color="black" engine="2.0L" drivetrain="FWD">Hyundai Sonata<Condition id="5">Excellent<Running>Yes</Running></Condition></Car>
    <Car year="2007" color="silver" engine="2.4L" drivetrain="AWD">Audi A4<Condition id="4">Good<Running>Sometimes</Running></Condition></Car>
    <Car year="2009" color="gray" engine="2.0L" drivetrain="FWD">Mitsubishi Lancer<Condition id="3">Fair<Running>Yes</Running></Condition></Car>
    <Car year="1996" color="green" engine="5.0L" drivetrain="4WD">Jeep Grand Cherokee<Condition id="3">Fair<Running>No</Running></Condition></Car>
</Cars>
```

I am trying to print the year and make/model of each car, however, when I run my code, it prints the make/model, along with the values of Condition and Running, as such:

```
id: 2012
value: Hyundai SonataExcellentYes

id: 2007
value: Audi A4GoodSometimes

id: 2009
value: Mitsubishi LancerFairYes

id: 1996
value: Jeep Grand CherokeeFairNo
```

I'm wondering how I can isolate each of those values. Here is my code:

```
class ParseCars {
static void main(String[] args) {

    def carsXml = new XmlSlurper().parse("xml/cars.xml")

    carsXml.Cars.Car.each{
        def car = new Car()
        car.year = it.@year.text() as Integer
        car.makeModel = it

        println "id: ${car.year}"
        println "value: ${car.makeModel}"
        println " "
    }
}
}
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on dealing with nested values where the parent tags also contain values like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodeChild.text()` will give you the text of all child nodes. You can use [`NodeChild.localText()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html#localText--) to retrieve only the text of direct child nodes.

So

```
car.makeModel = it.localText()
```

will do what you want.

If you need to access children individually (e.g. the first child) you can need to go to the actual `Node` first. Then you can use [`children()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/Node.html#children--) to get a list of child nodes and access them individually:

```
it[0].children()[0] // Text node, e.g. Hyundai Sonata
it[0].children()[1] // Condition node, e.g. <Condition id="5">Excellent<Running>Yes</Running></Condition>
```